# Troubleshooting "The security Database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship."

Tags: windows-7, docking-station

I'm trying to connect via docking station with Lenovo x-200 Win 7, and I'm getting this massage:

> The security Database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but in addition to having an issue with the security database (like Active Directory), you may be experiencing a networking issue. Perhaps the port replication on the docking station is not working properly, so while you are connected via your laptop, you can properly access the security database, however while you are docked, you cannot because the port on the dock is not working properly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - it probably means that you are trying to log on with a domain account but there was a machine with the same name on the domain since the last time you logged on.
Log in as your local machine administrator account, leave and re-join the domain.
Reboot and it should work.

Comment: Could also happen if machine account in ADUC was inadvertently deleted.